# ¿Cómo podría ir aumentando la longitud de una tabla hasta que introduzca un -1?

Tags: java, java-8

**Mi objetivo es que mientras el valor introducido de un tesoro almacenado en la tabla sea diferente a -1, vaya aumentando la longitud de la tabla, lo he intentado de varias formas y nada... Esto es lo más cerca que he estado de lo que yo quiero hacer.  **

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tablaTesoros[] = new int[1];
    System.out.println("Hola indiana...");
    int longitud = tablaTesoros.length;
    int valor = 0;
    
    System.out.println("Valor del tesoro 0");
    valor = sc.nextInt();
    tablaTesoros[0] = valor;
        
        while (valor != -1) {
            tablaTesoros = Arrays.copyOf(tablaTesoros, longitud++);
            for (int i = 1; i <= tablaTesoros.length-1; i++) {
                System.out.println("Valor del tesoro "+i );
                valor = sc.nextInt();
                tablaTesoros[i] = valor;
                
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tablaTesoros));
    }
```

Comment: Usa list en vez de arrays normales si no no se puede un array normal tiene un tamaño predeterminado

Comment: Me ha dicho el profesor que se tiene que hacer sin el ArrayList...

Comment: Puedes crear un método que reciba un array y el dato que ingresa, en ese método copias todo el contenido de el primer array y pones al final el dato en un segundo array que tendra el tamaño del primero + 1, en pocas palabras un copia y pega solo que al final añades el dato que ingreso el usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class indianaJones {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Hola Indiana...");
    double tesoros[] = new double[1];
    
    /*La variable longitud guardará la longitud de la tabla tesoros, e inicializaremos 
    una variable(i) que empezará en 0.
    */
    int longitud = tesoros.length; 
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Valor del tesoro "+i);
    double valor = sc.nextInt();
    tesoros[i] = valor;
    
    /*En este bucle estamos poniendo la condición de que si el valor 
    introducido en la variable valor es diferente a -1 que la variable i 
    incremente en uno y la longitud también, a su vez se copiará una tabla
    igual que la anterior solo que esta vez tomará la nueva longitud 
    incrementada.
    */
    while (valor != -1) {
        i++;
        longitud++;
        tesoros = Arrays.copyOf(tesoros, longitud);
        
        /*En este bucle que forma parte de la acción del blucle que contiene a éste,
        pedirá el nuevo valor para el nuevo índice, ya que la longitud la 
        hemos incrementado.
        */
        for (int j = i; j <= tesoros.length-1; j++) {
            System.out.println("Valor del tesoro "+j);
            valor = sc.nextDouble();
            tesoros[j] = valor;
        }
        /*En esta condición estamos declarando que si el valor introducido
        sea igual a -1, copie una tabla solo que la longitud tendrá un
        índice menos el cuál será el último, el cuál será -1.
        */
        if (valor == -1) {
            tesoros = Arrays.copyOf(tesoros, tesoros.length-1);
            
            
            
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Esta es la solución que me ha servido a mí, perdona por no publicarla antes... No tenía mucho tiempo.

Answer (score 2):

Para que lo modifiques un poco y entiendes como funciona lo hice usando un array auxiliar llamado Ntabla pero puedes hacerlo usando solo el primero, seria bueno que lo intentaras para que mejores el código mio.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tablaTesoros[] = new int[1];
        System.out.println("Hola indiana...");
        int longitud = tablaTesoros.length;
        int valor = 0;
        
        System.out.println("Valor del tesoro 0");
        
        valor = sc.nextInt();
        tablaTesoros[0] = valor;
        int[] NtablaTesoros=Arrays.copyOf(tablaTesoros,longitud); //Nueva tabla con los valores de la origianl
            int i=1; //contador
            while (valor != -1) {  
                valor=sc.nextInt(); //ingresa un numero el usuario
                if (valor==-1) {break;} // si es -1 salte del while para no guardarlo en la tabla
                 NtablaTesoros = Arrays.copyOf(NtablaTesoros, i+1); //sobreescribe lo que hay en la nueva tabla con los datos que ya tenia y ponle de tamaño 1 mas
                NtablaTesoros[i]=valor; // guarda en la posición del contador 
                i++; // sumale 1 al contador
  
                
            }
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(NtablaTesoros));
}
```